# How to create div with angle

Tags: html, css

I would like to create div like this picture:

[image]

So far I created this:

```
<div style="width: 300px; height: 200px; left:20px; top: 40px;">
<div style="width: 300px; height: 20px; top: 0px; background-color: #76b900; border-radius: 3px; "/>

</div>
```

How I can add color gradient like the picture. And also how I can add 45 degree angle like the picture?

Comment: If you don't have to support old IE, this can be done in CSS alone. Does that suit you?

Comment: Yes, would you show me how to do this, please?

Comment: Sure. I was messing around on jsFiddle, but it was painfully slow, so I switched to codepen. I added my solution below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to use a pseudo element with the same gradient as the main element, but diagonally across, then rotate it 45 degrees:

```css
h1 {
    background: linear-gradient(#5FA309, #3B8018);
    position: relative;
    line-height: 30px;
}

​h1:after {
    content: '';
    background: linear-gradient(top left, #5FA309, #3B8018);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px; right: -11px;
    width: 21px;
    height: 21px;
}​
```

Here's a demo: http://codepen.io/JosephSilber/pen/bFfqn

**P.S.** Don't forget vendor prefixes in production...

Comment: No, but Firefox 16 should be able to display that properly, at least according to <a href="http://www.caniuse.com>caniuse.com</a>. A common problem is that people have an ad blocker on and it impairs the functioning of tools like JSFiddle and CodePen.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you would need 2 divs to accomplish this using just css.

One as a block with the text and on the right side you should float a div and apply a similar style to this:

[How do CSS triangles work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-does-this-css-triangle-shape-work)

I would personally consider images.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use 2 `div`s, or you can use an `:after` pseudo-element with an image of the arrow point alone.

EDIT:
Come to think of it, using 2 skewed divs would also require you to use a `:before` pseudo-element with the image of the arrow point.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
<div class-"container">
 <div class="arrow-body"></div>
 <div class="arrow-right"></div>
</div>

.container {
 width:300px;
 overflow:auto;
}

.arrow-body {
 width:270px;
 height:60px;
 background:green;
 float:left;
}

.arrow-right {
 width: 0; 
 height: 0; 
 border-top: 30px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;
 border-left: 30px solid green;
 float:left;
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't allow gradients, and could easily be accomplished with the two pseudo elements. No need for all that extra markup (unless you're still supporting IE6, in which case I feel *really* sorry for you).